# Update case when sql query to vba

Tags: sql-server, vba

I've been trying to convert the below code from SQL Server to run directly from Excel VBA. But unable to do so.

```sql
Update Legal 
Set Category = Case 
                  when datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]) > 9 
                     then 'Blue' 
                  when datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]) < 9 
                       and datediff(month, GETDATE(), [end date]) > 1 
                     then 'Orange'
                  when datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]) < 2 
                     then 'Red'
               End 
where classification = 'A'

Select 
    classification, 
    datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]), 
    Category 
from 
    Legal
```

Into VBA like below

```vb
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLSelect As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlcmd as string

cbb = Environ("computername")

With Sheet3.Range("A4:Z" & Rows.Count)
.ClearContents
'.ClearFormats
 End With


sqlcmd = "Update Legal Set Category = Case" & _
" when datediff(month,GETDATE(),[End date])>9 then 'Blue'" & _
" when datediff(month,GETDATE(),[End date])<9 and datediff(month,GETDATE(),[end date])>1 then 'Orange'" & _
" when datediff(month,GETDATE(),[End date])<2 then 'Red'" & _
" End " & _
" where classification = 'A'"

  Debug.Print sqlcmd

With Sheet3.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Login_ID;Password=Password;Data Source=Server_Name;Use Procedure f" _
    , _
    "or Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=" & cbb & ";Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collatio" _
    , "n when possible=False;Initial Catalog=DB_Name"), Destination:=Sheet3.Range( _
    "$A$4")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = sqlcmd 
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceConnectionFile = _
    "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\My Data Sources\xxxxx.odc"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = _
    "AP_123"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

This query works absolutely in SQL Server. But I get the following error in VBA:

> The query did not run, or the database table could not be opened.
>
> Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external database is available and hasn't been moved or reorganized, then try the operation again.

Kindly help me guys!! Been trying this for weeks!

P.S. Do not require a Power Query as it will ask for credentials to the other users whom do not have access to the server

Comment: Note that you have two queries there, not one (an `UPDATE` followed by a `SELECT`.) You will probably need to run each query separately, and we'll need to see your code that actually runs them.

Comment: sure Matt.. will try and let u know ASAP

Comment: @MattGibson.. I tried just running the Update query alone.. but that too didnt work..... I've updated my VBA code

Comment: Why are you trying to move this away from the database? It should be a stored procedure that you can call from your VBA code.

Comment: @SeanLange .. I'm a newbie and trying this out.. Apologies as i do not understand your statement

Comment: An UPDATE query updates records in the database. It doesn't make sense to link that to a table or a range. There will be no results returned.  It DOES make sense to link the SELECT query to a table or range though. It feels like an ADODB solution would be better here instead of an external table query type thing you have going on.

Comment: @JNevil .. I had a Select Query as well, but was updated by Matt Gibson to run each query seperately.. So i just tried the Update query but my guess.. even tho' it will not fetch a result.. it should execute the query, right.. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.. Thanks

Comment: You said you have this working in the database already. Taking code out of the database to a program is not usually a good idea. It is challenging to maintain that way. And as you are discovering creates a syntactical minefield. It is not clear to me what you are really trying to do here. Are you trying to somehow limit this update to only update rows based on some range in your excel document? This kind of thing is normally done with a where clause.

Comment: Honestly, I've never tried. It really doesn't make sense to me though to add a querytable that has a SQL query under the hood that doesn't actually return data.It also seems very odd that you would have to run an UPDATE on a table EVERY time you select from it. Why not just have the CASE statement in your SELECT....? It's all a little strange.

Comment: @Sean Lange .. I'm trying to create a dashboard based on the end date of contracts and on their classification.  So whenever the user clicks status in Excel I would run this update query to refresh my table of contracts by comparing today's date with the contract's end date. Hope this clarifies .. I'm also open to other possible ways to do so. could you kindly guide me?

Comment: @jnevill.. Hope my previous comment clarifies your query

Comment: Create a stored procedure that does your update. Execute that procedure when the user clicks the button in Excel. Then query the data and populate your spreadsheet. I think you are making this way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: It still seems like an odd solution to run an UPDATE EVERY time instead of just writing the logic in the SELECT to this transformation. Like a total misuse of the database.

Comment: @JNevill I totally agree but the situation is so incredibly fuzzy to me.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear and I think any attempt to execute the UPDATE from excel is way off base and is headed far down the XY Problem rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, simply separate the two queries by first actually running the action `UPDATE` statement and then connect your QueryTable to `SELECT` statement. You can even shorten connection string in *Source* argument:

```vb
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Server_Name As String, Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String, Password As String
Dim conn_str As String, SQLSelect As String, sqlcmd as string

cbb = Environ("computername")

With Sheet3.Range("A4:Z" & Rows.Count)
     .ClearContents
     '.ClearFormats
End With

conn_str = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Login_ID;Password=Password;" & _
           "Data Source=Server_Name;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;" & _
           "Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=" & cbb & ";Use Encryption for Data=False;" & _
           "Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=DB_Name"

Cn.Open conn_str

' EXECUTE ACTION QUERY
sqlcmd = "UPDATE Legal SET Category = Case" & _
         " when datediff(month,GETDATE(),[End date])>9 then 'Blue'" & _
         " when datediff(month,GETDATE(),[End date])<9 and " & _
         "      datediff(month,GETDATE(),[end date])>1 then 'Orange'" & _
         " when datediff(month,GETDATE(),[End date])<2 then 'Red'" & _
         " End " & _
         " where classification = 'A'"

Cn.Execute sqlcmd

' CONNECT TO SELECT QUERY
sqlcmd = "SELECT classification, datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]), Category " & _
         " FROM Legal;"

With Sheet3.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;" & conn_str), Destination:=Sheet3.Range( _
    "$A$4")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = sqlcmd 
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceConnectionFile = _
    "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\My Data Sources\xxxxx.odc"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = _
    "AP_123"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank u so much for helping me guys...!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the stored procedure method. In SSMS, run this one time

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateAndGetLegal
AS
    UPDATE Legal
    SET    Category = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), [End date]) > 9 THEN 'Blue'
                           WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), [End date]) < 9
                                AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), [end date]) > 1 THEN 'Orange'
                           WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), [End date]) < 2 THEN 'Red'
                      END
    WHERE  classification = 'A'

    SELECT classification
         , DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), [End date])
         , Category
    FROM   Legal
```

That will create a stored procedure that runs the update and returns the SELECT results.

In Excel, I almost never have to `.Add` a ListObject. Sometimes I have to change the SQL statement of an existing ListObject, but once a table is created, you don't really need to create it again. So I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but here's how it would look in one of my projects.

I create an Excel file (or template if it's something I'm generating on the fly). In that file, I create an external data ListObject with a commandtext of

```
EXEC UpdateAndGetLegal
```

Then if the user simply refreshes the table, I'm done. If I need my code to refresh the table, it's

```
Sheet3.ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh
```

If you're passing Windows credentials through to SQL Server, all of the users will need EXECUTE rights for the stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a bit of a guess here, but it's based on something that feels off.

Every time you run your SELECT to get some data

```
Select 
    classification, 
    datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]), 
    Category 
from 
    Legal
```

You first run an UPDATE...

```
Update Legal 
Set Category = Case 
                  when datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]) > 9 
                     then 'Blue' 
                  when datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]) < 9 
                       and datediff(month, GETDATE(), [end date]) > 1 
                     then 'Orange'
                  when datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]) < 2 
                     then 'Red'
               End 
where classification = 'A'
```

That's strange and I can't think of a usecase where this would be appropriate in any database. Instead you could just have a SELECT all by itself:

```
Select 
    classification, 
    datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]), 
    Case WHEN classification = 'A' 
        THEN
            CASE
                  when datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]) > 9 
                     then 'Blue' 
                  when datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]) < 9 
                       and datediff(month, GETDATE(), [end date]) > 1 
                     then 'Orange'
                  when datediff(month, GETDATE(), [End date]) < 2 
                     then 'Red'
               End 
        ELSE Category
        END
from 
    Legal
```

That does the same thing, but without touching the underlying data in `Legal`. This SELECT is the one that you want to shoehorn in to your VBA/QueryTable.

Comment: Thank you.. As you guys suggested after executing the update query and running the Select query.. I got the result..